# Installing windows 11 from a bootable USB but SSD HD not showing

Tags: hard-drive, boot, windows-11

I have an asus tuf 17 laptop with a 512GB SSD hard drive.

For some reason the windows 10 installation got corrupted so I formatted the SSD hard disk from command line after restarting windows using disk part. But I never set the new formatted volume to active. I restarted the laptop and when I go to Bios, it detect the ssd drive.

I used another PC to create a bootable windows 11 Installation usb.

Plugged in the USB on my aus laptop and entered setup but the setup could not detect my SSD drive. I went to command like and tried to list all drives, I only get the USB drive and not the ssd Drive.

Any suggestion please?

Thanks

Comment: Be sure Secure Boot is enabled, UEFI mode is enabled (CSM is disabled), and GPT is being used.

Comment: Secure Boot is enabled from bios, the laptop successfully boot from usb. When I start the windows installation process and go to select the drive. No drive is shown. Even when I go to command line and list the drives. I only get the USB drive, the SSD drive is not shown. Maybe because I formatted it and not set it to active?

Comment: The fact no drive is shown is an indication the installation media wasn’t booted with UEFI mode enabled or the drive was either formatted with MBR instead of being completely unallocated.

Comment: I think the UEFI mode is enabled with NTFS file system. I think the issue is the way I formatted the ssd hard disk using diskpart. The disk before format was shown as unknown. When I formated it and restarted the laptop, the ssd won't show anymore when I boot from usb

Comment: If the drive has a file system, is it MBR or GPT, Windows cannot be installed while in UEFI mode on MBR. **My suggestion is to delete all partitions on the drive.** Then you don’t have to worry about that particular conflict or clarify if it’s MBR or not.

Comment: Got it. I made the bootable usb using rufus. I used GPT and not MBR. So if I used MBR partition scheme instead while creating the bootable usb the ssd drive will be shown when I install windows? I cant delete the partitions on the SsD drive because I can't access it from the command line

Comment: Talking about GPT on the SSD not the installation media.  My suggestion skip Rufus and use the install media creation tool directly from Microsoft to create the installation media

Comment: Ok will do and get back to you. Thanks a lot for your help